# Azure returning incorrect MySQL version. MySQL 5.7.8 or higher is required to run Craft CMS

Tags: mysql

I have upgraded one of our sites to Craft CMS 4 and moved it to a staging site on Azure. The front-end works but the control panel gives the MySQL 5.7.8 or higher is required to run Craft CMS error.

[image]

It looks like the wrong MySQL version is being returned by `PDO::ATTR_SERVER_VERSION`.

`$conn->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_SERVER_VERSION)` returns: 5.6.47.0

`$conn->query('select version()')->fetchColumn()` returns: 5.7.32.log

MySQL Workbench also returns 5.7.32

Anybody else encountered this problem or have any suggested workarounds?

Thanks!

Comment: The only workaround that I have found so far is to manually change $requiredMySqlVersion in \vendor\craft\server-check\server\RequirementsChecker.php

Comment: Hi there, this looks like an issue in your hosting environment. Changing the required version in craft vendor folder is not recommended. I would pursue Azure hosting assistance for why your environment's MySQL version is coming up as the wrong one.

Comment: @cherrykoda Yeah, it certainly wasn't ideal.

I found a solution. By changing the DB_PORT environment variable to 3308. It now reports the MySQL version as 5.7.29.0  Still doesn't match what select version() reports, but it removes the error.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/single-server/concepts-connect-to-a-gateway-node

Thanks!

Comment: @Watsonian Glad you got it sorted! Would you mind adding what you found as an official answer in case it helps someone in the future?

Comment: @BradBell Oh, yes! Added now. Thanks!

Comment: @Watsonian thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this problem was to change DB_PORT to 3308 rather than 3306. This then returns a MySQL version of 5.7.29.0. While it still doesn't match the actual server version, it removes the error in the control panel.

Full details can be found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/single-server/concepts-connect-to-a-gateway-node